# Align an element to the right side of the flexbox with flexbox

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

## Problem:

Im trying to put my change button to the end of the flexbox, but its always with the title.

## What ive tried

1.Ive tried to put the button in a div.
2.Ive tried all the alinge statements.
3.Ive put an !Important behind the aling statements

### How it is

[image how it is currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bjac.png)

### How it should be

[image how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXDeT.png)

## What im using

Angular: 10.1.6

## Code

### Html

```
<div class="flexboxTitleandChangeButton">
 <h1 style="margin-top: 10px">{{ projekt?.titel }}</h1>
 <button class="flexboxChangeButton" sbbButton [mode]="'secondary'">Change</button>
</div>
```

### SCSS

```
.flexboxTitleandChangeButton {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}
.flexboxChangeButton{
 margin-top: 20px;
 align-items: flex-end !important;
}
```

Comment: For class .flexboxTitleandChangeButton just change justify-content: 'space-between';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to have is `display: flex;` on the `.flexboxTitleandChangeButton` div and `margin-left: auto` on the 'Change' button.

It will then be positioned to the far right on the screen. The rest of the code can be removed (is not needed).

*Side note:* Nice starting point in code you provided.

```css
.flexboxTitleandChangeButton {
  display: flex;
}

.flexboxChangeButton {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexboxTitleandChangeButton">
  <h1 style="margin-top: 10px">{{ projekt?.titel }}</h1>
  <button class="flexboxChangeButton" sbbButton [mode]="'secondary'">Change</button>
</div>
```